# if-else in each method (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code returns the following result:

```
0: 000,
1: 100,
2: 200,
...
40: 4000
```

I would like to add a `if-else`.
`var minValue === 100; var maxValue === 300` and display only elements with `value.innerText <= minValue && value.innerText >= maxValue`

How can I add it to this code? + How can I add a function to these elements, eg that any element that meets the condition if has been a function `.click();`

```
var labels = $('.st-weight-class').find('.filter-panel--option-list label');

labels.each(function (index, value) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + value.innerText);
});
```

Comment: Could you please more explanation to it, will be easy for us to help?

Comment: showing your HTML snippet for the `.st-weight-class` and `filter-panel--option-list label` would help us understand what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach click event inside each method and add condition

Try this:

```
var labels = $('.st-weight-class').find('.filter-panel--option-list label');

var minValue = 100;
var maxValue = 300;

labels.each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if($(this).text()>=minValue && $(this).text()<=maxValue) {
            console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
        }
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function getLabelsInRange( labels, minValue, maxValue) {
  return labels.filter( label => parseInt( label.innerText ) >= minValue && parseInt( label.innerText ) <= maxValue );
}
```

This would then return all the labels that are inside the range of `minValue` & `maxValue`, by using

```
let matchingLabels = getLabelsInRange( labels, 100, 300 );
```

I did invert your condition, as I believe you want everything within the range of `minValue >= x >= maxValue`

Comment: I have to call it in my function each?

Comment: @JSExpress1 No, filter will go through all items in your `labels` variable, so it will use filter instead of each. This will only retrieve the matching labels, how you display them afterwards, that is something for you to decide :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var minValue === 100; var maxValue === 300;
```

That is not valid javascript assignment. Maybe you meant to say:

```
var minValue = 100; var maxValue = 300;
```

What is stopping you from typing it straight forward as you have defined in your question?

```
if(value.innerText<minValue || value.innerText>maxValue) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + value.innerText);
}
```

```js
var labels = $('.st-weight-class').find('.filter-panel--option-list label');

var minValue = 100;
var maxValue = 300;

labels.each(function (index, value) {
  if(value.innerText<minValue || value.innerText>maxValue) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + value.innerText);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='st-weight-class'>
  <div class='filter-panel--option-list'>
    <label>10</label>
    <label>50</label>
    <label>70</label>
    <label>90</label>
    <label>100</label>
    <label>200</label>
    <label>250</label>
    <label>300</label>
    <label>350</label>
    <label>400</label>
    <label>650</label>
    <label>900</label>
  </div>
</div>
```